# How do I disable pylint for the name of my root folder?

Tags: python, pylint

when I

```
touch __init__.py; pylint $(pwd); rm __init__.py
```

over my project folder, it triggers a warning complaining about the folder name:

```
************* Module car-onboard-computer
__init__.py:1:0: C0103: Module name "car-onboard-computer" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 9.93/10 (previous run: 9.93/10, +0.00)
```

This module is the root folder. The name "car-onboard-computer" is provided from GitLab, so I can't do much to change it (even wouldn't make sense). How do I disable pylint for the name of my root folder?

ps: adding `invalid-name` to pylintrc `disable=` list would affect the whole project, so it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: But `car-onboard-computer` isn't really a good name for a package (convention aside), because with `-` it's not a valid / importable package name anyways. And whatever the remote repo name is, you can name it locally anything you want.

Comment: how can i rename it locally? you mean just normal renaming?

Comment: I mean when you clone it, you can chose what directory is it locally cloned into, e.g. `git clone REMOTE_URL local_dir`, but you can also rename/move the directory at any later time.

Comment: Jenkins generates kebab-case-project-folder-name - and pylint counts it as invalid-name. So the issue is still actual: how to disable invalid-name rule for the project root folder?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question and finally solved it today.

**Bonus**: if your root-dir is autogenerated - will be work too. (hi, Jenkins & k8s autogenerated pods)

### Solution

```sh
#!/bin/bash
current_dir=$(basename $(pwd))
touch __init__.py
pylint $(pwd) --good-names=${current_dir}
rm __init__.py
```

or in one row

```sh
current_dir=$(basename $(pwd)); touch __init__.py; pylint $(pwd) --good-names=${current_dir}; rm __init__.py
```

**Solution for Jenkins**

```sh
current_dir=$(basename ${WORKSPACE})
touch __init__.py
pylint ${WORKSPACE} --rcfile=.pylintrc --good-names=${current_dir}
rm __init__.py
```